# How to make `ESC` key act like a real Meta modifier key?

Tags: key-bindings, escape

I would like to make the `ESC` key act like a Meta (modifier) key.

For example, when I move backward by words by (`M-b`), I want to keep my pinky finger on `ESC`, not press it once for each backward move. I want to change the key behavior only for Emacs.

Also, is there any disadvantage to doing this (such as interfering with other commands)?

Comment: You want to make `ESC` act as a modifier key? I don't think this is possible - at the Emacs level at least.

Comment: @Drew, Yes I want to make ESC act as a modifier key.

Comment: What is the reason you want to do this? Perhaps this is an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/66377/231821)?

Comment: I changed my Caps-Lock to ESC in system wide. As a newcomer to Emacs, I thought it could be nice to have second Meta key on the left side of the keyboard. (I have already one on the right.) I don't want to keep  on ESC each time to move backwards by words.

Comment: What OS are you using? If Linux, you may be able to use xcape to achieve what you want, as mentioned in this post: https://askubuntu.com/q/177824